# Как ограничить выбор даты

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо, чтобы нельзя было выбрать дату, которая не наступила т.е. сегодня 01.05.2020 и нельзя выбрать 02.05.2020
Пробовал делать через `DisplayDateEnd`, но пользователь может сам написать дату и тем самым это ограничение не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю функционала вашего проекта и стиля кода, но в голову приходит что то типа проверки

```
if (UsersDate >= DateTime.Now)
{
MessageBox.Show("Wrong Date");
}
```

Comment: Лучше уж сразу тогда `throw new Exception("Wrong date")`

Comment: ну да, можно и так, да вообще можно много как, это не такой уж клинический случай, где нет выхода)))

Answer (score 0):

Для ограничение определенных дат, можно использовать метод `BlackoutDates`

В моем случаи вот так:

**XAML**

```
<DatePicker x:Name="date_Birth" Language="ru" ToolTip="Дата рождения"/>
```

**CS**

```
date_Birth.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1),
                             new DateTime(9999,12,31)));
```